# Update , con select count ACCES

Tags: sql

Estoy intentando actualizar una tabla de *access* con datos de esta tabla. Concretamente la cuenta.

```
UPDATE PRODUCTO P, HISTORICO H SET V1= count(menaje)
WHERE P.codigo=H.codigo;
```

La cosa es que me da un error de que no incluye V1 como parte de una funcion de agregado. Se que esto se soluciona poniendo el GROUP BY pero soy incapaz de encontrar donde.

Si le quito el `count(menaje)` y lo dejo como menaje funciona bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar a guardar el resultado del `COUNT` en una variable y luego hacer el `UPDATE`:

```
SET @COUNT_MENAJE=(SELECT COUNT(codigo) FROM HISTORICO H WHERE
P.codigo=H.codigo); 

UPDATE PRODUCTO P SET V1=@COUNT_MENAJE;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Lo pruebo.

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que lo que quieres es actualizar el campo `V1` de la tabla `PRODUCTO` con la cuenta del número de registros que hay con su `codigo` en la tabla `HISTORICO`, podrías simplemente hacer un `UPDATE` normal igualando el campo a actualizar con el `SELECT COUNT` de la otra tabla, tal que así:

```
UPDATE PRODUCTO P SET V1= (SELECT COUNT(codigo) FROM HISTORICO H WHERE P.codigo=H.codigo);
```

Otra cosa que podrías probar es hacer un bucle para ir haciendo los `UPDATES`. Algo así:

```
dthistorico.Open "SELECT codigo, COUNT(menaje) AS contador FROM HISTORICO GROUP BY codigo", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
Do Until dthistorico.EOF
    CurrentProject.Connection.Execute  
      "UPDATE PRODUCTOS SET V1=" & dthistorico.Fields("contador") & " WHERE codigo=" & dthistorico.Fields("codigo")
    dthistorico.MoveNext
Loop
dthistorico.Close
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Irene.

Ya habia probado algo parecido pero no funciona. Me dice que la operacion debe de usar una consulta actualizable. 

Por lo que he visto en access no puedes actualizar una tabla a partir de una consulta.

Comment: Ok. Tus tablas tienen identificadores únicos? Una primary key que haga a los registros únicos? Igual si das más detalles... estructura de tablas, código Access, etc... te puedo ayudar mejor

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu interes Irene. He editado arriba la estructura aproximadamente de las tablas. No tienen claves ni nada. Yo he heredado la BBDD asi